# php bin/magento setup:di:compile command throws Source class "-------" for "-------" generation does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1

I have added a Repository interface in my Api directory and it's implementation in located under Models directory.

I have setup the preference for the interface in etc/di.xml.

When I run bin/magento setup:di:compile the following error is thrown in the console.

> Source class "\Namespace\Module\Model\PostInterface" for
>   "Namespace\Module\Model\PostRepository" generation does not exist.

I have no idea why the system is searching for "\Namespace\Module\Model\PostInterface" while I have mentioned clearly the location of the implementation class in di.xml.

Any suggestions are welcome with thanks !!

**More Info:**

> When I remove the Repository implementation file i.e;
>   app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/PostRepository.php (imlpements
>   app/code/Namespace/Module/Api/PostRepositoryInterface.php), the error
>   disappears.
>
> Also, when I rename the file from
>   app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/PostRepository.php to
>   app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/PostRepositoryy.php, the error
>   disappears.

Is there any conventions that needs to be followed while using Repositories ?

Comment: I get the same error and removing or renaming the file does not help. It's crazy.

Comment: Did you add `<preference for="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\PostInterface" type="Namespace\Module\Model\PostRepository" />` in your `di.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of Code analysis and Google searches, I found the fix for this problem. Adding the following to the di.xml fixed this issue.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Model\Entity\RepositoryFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="entities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\PostInterface" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Api\Data\PostRepositoryInterface
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: Did you add `<preference for="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\PostInterface" type="Namespace\Module\Model\PostRepository" />` in your `di.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove var/generation and var/di folders
Then try again with command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I have followed these steps and the error still appears.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a custom module, it was a typo in the `composer.json` file:

```json
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Vendor\\Namespace\\": ""
    }
}
```

in the `Vendor\\Namespace`. It might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post now, but for anyone else that's still experiencing this, a fix that seems to work is rather than defining the repository interface as a `use` statement, add its fully qualified name, for example:

```
use Vendor\Module\Interface;

class MyClass implements Interface
```

Becomes:

```
class MyClass implements \Vendor\Module\Interface
```

This fixed this for us when compiling repositories on M2 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error after trying to generate di and it even persisted on any cli command for some reason.

Try to delete **generated/***