# Magento 2 Repositories code generation error

Tags: magento-2.1

When i execute this command

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Error like this

> Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 44.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tutorial\Megamenu\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Element\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image' not found in /var/www/magento_store/app/code/Tutorial/Megamenu/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Element/Image.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Tutorial\Megamenu\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Element\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image' not found in /var/www/app/code/Tutorial/Megamenu/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Element/Image.php on line 9

And mysql error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: 
Base table or view not found: 1146 
Table 'magento_store.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, 
query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `design_config_grid_flat` AS `main_table`
```

I try to solve this errors from

[Que:-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181650/fatal-error-on-execution-of-php-dmemory-limit-5g-bin-magento-setupdicompile)
[Que:-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146496/what-i-do-if-setupdicompile-fails) [Que:-3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165630/bin-magento-setupdicompile-throws-source-class-for-generat)

But my problem can not be solve.

Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error , indicate that  ***design flat at table does not exist at your system.***

So, you ***should create this table  using direct  mysql.***

> CREATE TABLE `design_config_grid_flat` (   `entity_id` int(10)
>   UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',   `store_website_id` int(11)
>   DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id',   `store_group_id` int(11)
>   DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id',   `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT
>   NULL COMMENT 'Store_id',   `theme_theme_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
>   COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>   COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat';
>
> ALTER TABLE `design_config_grid_flat`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
>   ADD KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID`
>   (`store_website_id`),   ADD KEY
>   `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`store_group_id`),   ADD KEY
>   `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`); ALTER TABLE
>   `design_config_grid_flat` ADD FULLTEXT KEY
>   `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID` (`theme_theme_id`);

***Also to avoid the  memory_limit issue in compile run below query for compile***

> sudo php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: thank you very much.my design configure solve after i create that table.and again 'sudo php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento setup:di:compile' error throws **''Fatal error: Class 'Tutorial\Megamenu\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Element\Magento\Fram‌​ework\Data\Form\Elem‌​ent\Image' not found in /var/www/app/code/Tutorial/Megamenu/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Ele‌​ment/Image.php on line 9'**